# Is there a better way to divide this string into substrings?

Tags: java, append, substring, indexof, lastindexof

I am trying to extract the `"first_name"` and `"last_name"` from a long string of information that look like this:

```
{
    "123123123": {
        "id": "12321312****",
        "email": "***************",
        "first_name": "Marcus",
        "gender": "male",
        "last_name": "Bengtsson",
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/123123123/",
        "locale": "en_EN",
        "middle_name": "Peter",
        "name": "Marcus Peter Bengtsson"
    }
}
```

The way I do it (which is probably horribly wrong and a pretty bad solution) is that I firstly extract the substring from `"first_name"` to `"link"` with this code:

```
String subStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("first_name"), str.lastIndexOf("link"));
```

Then I get:

`first_name":"Marcus","gender":"male","last_name":"Bengtsson","`

Then I do the same thing but from `":"` to `"gender"` to get the `"first_name`:

```
String firstNameOfUser = subStr.substring(subStr.indexOf(":")+2, subStr.lastIndexOf("gender")-3);
```

Then the same thing for `"last_name"`:

```
String lastNameOfUser = subStr.substring(subStr.indexOf(""last_name"")+12, subStr.lastIndexOf(",")-1);
```

And lastly I append the both strings with a space in between:

```
String nameOfUser = new StringBuilder().append(firstNameOfUser).append(" ").append(lastNameOfUser).toString();
```

And then I get:

`Marcus Bengtsson`

There is probably a much better way to do this but I can't seam to figure out how.

Comment: Use a JSON parser like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: Looks like a json string. So you should use a json parser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) so it would be **much** better to parse it as such using one of many available parsers and then extract the data.

Comment: Okay, but the data I'm fetching is from a webbpage. How do I save it down first? Im using InputStream and BufferedReader to get the data from the site and then I patch it up to a String with StringBuilder. This seams like a whole different question now.

Comment: Most libraries are capable of using `InputStream` directly. You won't even need to build a string for them.

Comment: Well I tried the Json thing but now I am not able to save the fields from the JSONObject. I get the error `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["first_name"] not found.` But when I first print out the whole JSONObject I clearly see all the fields. No clue of what I am doing wrong... Oh never mind, I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The given String is a JSON, use the [JSONParser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) to parse it to json and then extract the data needed.

Answer (score 0):

thats a json? visit this link [JSON Example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp)

```
nameOfUser = 123123123.first_name + " " + 123123123.last_name;
```

i hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

As @Crozin wrote it looks like json but if you can't parse it in this way you can always use regex. Just use Matcher, Pattern with a regex `^.*\"first_name\":\"([a-zA-Z]+)\".*\"last_name\":\"([a-zA-Z]+)\".*$`.

Comment: I'd say you can't _always_ use regex. If the data is simple enough and you know what will be contained then it might work but since JSON can get quite complex regex will eventually break.

Comment: Downvote: it is a very poor, error prone solution. Regular expressions might look like a quick'n'easy solution but most of the time when you're dealing with complex, structured language (such as JSON) they're not.

Comment: As I wrote regex can be used if it can't be parsed as json.